# Highcharts with two sliding axes in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm using angular2-highcharts getting data from a service (Subject).
The result I would like to get is the one in the following picture:
[image]

With sliding red lines. Every time a new series is inserted in the chart (dynamically) the chart is updated via

```
this.chart.addSeries( series ,true)
```

And axes are drawn again with:

```
this.chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({ ...
```

Now I can't find a way to drag the axes around.I've tried with event handlers in addPlotLine but only few events are supported, and I've tried to attach event handler directly to

```
let el = this.chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.element;
```

But I'm stuck on this point. Are there any other easy ways to do this?

**I'd rather not use JQuery if possible**.

My chart container code:

```
export class ChartContainerComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(
    
    private cds:ChartDataService, 
    private elementRef:ElementRef,
    private changeDetector:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  currentSeries:any[];

  hasPlotLine:boolean=false;

  options:any={
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy'  

    },
    
    title: {
      text: 'GP% Vs fatturato'
    },
    
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source file'
    },
    
    xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#000',
      tickColor: '#000',

      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#000',
            font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
         }
      },


      title: {
        
        style: {
            color: '#333',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'

         },

        enabled: true,
        
        text: 'GP (%)'
      },
      startOnTick: true,
      endOnTick: true,
      showLastLabel: true
    },

    yAxis: {
      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      lineColor: '#000',
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickWidth: 1,
      tickColor: '#000',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#000',
            font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
         }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Fatturato (€)'
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        marker: {
          radius: 5,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: true,
              lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
            }
          }
        },
        
        states: {
          hover: {
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            }
          }
        },
        
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
          pointFormat: '{point.x} %, {point.y} E'
        }
      }
  },

  series:{}
  
  }
  
  chart:any;

  saveHighchartsInstance(hi){
    this.chart = hi;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        
        this.cds

            .getCategoriesStream()
            
            .map( (series:NameRevenueGp) =>{
                return {name:series.name, data:[[series.gp, series.revenue]]}
            })
            
            .subscribe( (series:any ) =>{
          // Add a series and redraw
          this.chart.addSeries( series ,true)
          
          let minX = this.chart.xAxis[0].dataMin;
          
          let minY = this.chart.yAxis[0].dataMin;
          
          let maxX = this.chart.xAxis[0].dataMax;
          
          let maxY = this.chart.yAxis[0].dataMax;
          
          let xaverage = (minX+maxX)/2; 
          let yaverage = (minY+maxY)/2; 
         
          this.chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('x-line');
          this.chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('y-line');

          this.chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            value:xaverage,
            color:'red',
            width:1,
            id:'x-line',
            events:{
              click:()=>{
                console.log('clicked');
              }
            }
          })

          this.chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            value:yaverage,
            color:'red',
            width:1,
            id:'y-line',
          }) 
          
          let clickX, clickY;

          
          // let el = this.chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.element;
          
          // el.ondrag=(e)=>{
          //   console.log("DRAGGED");
          // }
          
      
        }

      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Dragging plot lines is not supported by Highcharts. It's possible for **points** if you use **draggable points** plugin: https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points The solution here might be analyzing and modifying the code of this plugin so that it works for plot lines. You can also share your ideas on user voice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api